# I need to use the max() method on the date column, but I'm not getting it. Because the column is coming as a String. Can someone help me?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I'm using pandas to read Dataframe()...

After converting to datetime64, I need to use the max() method on that datetime column. But the problem is that I can't convert :(...

When I go to read my Excel Dataframe it is presenting the dates this way `2020-03-10T00:00:00.000Z`. I need to convert to datetime64 type but it is reading as string. Here's the example below:

```
df['Date'].dtype
```

Output:
dtype('O')

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'] )
```

Output:

ERROR:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
c:\Users\XXXXXX\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\arrays\datetimes.py in objects_to_datetime64ns(data, dayfirst, yearfirst, utc, errors, require_iso8601, allow_object)
   2084         try:
-> 2085             values, tz_parsed = conversion.datetime_to_datetime64(data)
   2086             # If tzaware, these values represent unix timestamps, so we

pandas\_libs\tslibs\conversion.pyx in pandas._libs.tslibs.conversion.datetime_to_datetime64()

TypeError: Unrecognized value type: <class 'str'>

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ParserError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-66-917cb86929c6> in <module>
----> 1 df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'] )

c:\Users\XXXXXX\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\tools\datetimes.py in to_datetime(arg, errors, dayfirst, yearfirst, utc, format, exact, unit, infer_datetime_format, origin, cache)
    799                 result = result.tz_localize(tz)
    800     elif isinstance(arg, ABCSeries):
--> 801         cache_array = _maybe_cache(arg, format, cache, convert_listlike)
    802         if not cache_array.empty:
    803             result = arg.map(cache_array)

c:\Users\XXXXXX\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\tools\datetimes.py in _maybe_cache(arg, format, cache, convert_listlike)
    176         unique_dates = unique(arg)
    177         if len(unique_dates) < len(arg):
--> 178             cache_dates = convert_listlike(unique_dates, format)
    179             cache_array = Series(cache_dates, index=unique_dates)
    180     return cache_array

c:\Users\XXXXXX\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\tools\datetimes.py in _convert_listlike_datetimes(arg, format, name, tz, unit, errors, infer_datetime_format, dayfirst, yearfirst, exact)
    463         assert format is None or infer_datetime_format
    464         utc = tz == "utc"
--> 465         result, tz_parsed = objects_to_datetime64ns(
    466             arg,
    467             dayfirst=dayfirst,

c:\Users\XXXXXX\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\arrays\datetimes.py in objects_to_datetime64ns(data, dayfirst, yearfirst, utc, errors, require_iso8601, allow_object)
   2088             return values.view("i8"), tz_parsed
   2089         except (ValueError, TypeError):
-> 2090             raise e
   2091 
   2092     if tz_parsed is not None:

c:\Users\XXXXXX\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\arrays\datetimes.py in objects_to_datetime64ns(data, dayfirst, yearfirst, utc, errors, require_iso8601, allow_object)
   2073 
   2074     try:
-> 2075         result, tz_parsed = tslib.array_to_datetime(
   2076             data,
   2077             errors=errors,

pandas\_libs\tslib.pyx in pandas._libs.tslib.array_to_datetime()

pandas\_libs\tslib.pyx in pandas._libs.tslib.array_to_datetime()

pandas\_libs\tslib.pyx in pandas._libs.tslib.array_to_datetime_object()

pandas\_libs\tslib.pyx in pandas._libs.tslib.array_to_datetime_object()

pandas\_libs\tslibs\parsing.pyx in pandas._libs.tslibs.parsing.parse_datetime_string()

c:\Users\XXXXXX\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\dateutil\parser\_parser.py in parse(timestr, parserinfo, **kwargs)
   1372         return parser(parserinfo).parse(timestr, **kwargs)
   1373     else:
-> 1374         return DEFAULTPARSER.parse(timestr, **kwargs)
   1375 
   1376 

c:\Users\XXXXXX\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\dateutil\parser\_parser.py in parse(self, timestr, default, ignoretz, tzinfos, **kwargs)
    650 
    651         if len(res) == 0:
--> 652             raise ParserError("String does not contain a date: %s", timestr)
    653 
    654         try:
    

ParserError: String does not contain a date: -
```

Comment: Cannot reproduce. Could you maybe share what your actual data looks like or at least its `describe`?

Comment: Please share some sample data, as I am unable to reproduce the error. Code pd.to_datetime(df['Date']) works fine with '2020-03-10T00:00:00.000Z' this datetime string.
Also check if your input as INT value as string instead of datetime, for example '23' or '1' or something similar.

Comment: My excel column of Date is coming 2022-03-13 in df.describe

Comment: Try to write like this: pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], errors='coerce'), it will output invalid formats or values as NaT.

Comment: My info Date:

```
0                       -
1     2026-01-15 00:00:00
2     2035-01-08 00:00:00
3     2026-01-15 00:00:00
4     2033-11-11 00:00:00
5                       -
6     2022-12-15 00:00:00
7     2023-03-15 00:00:00
8     2024-03-15 00:00:00
9                       -
10    2023-03-15 00:00:00
11    2023-09-15 00:00:00
12    2024-03-15 00:00:00
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see if this snippet helps you out, I have worked with some sample data and added some values to reproduce the error:

```py
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({'Date': ['2023-03-15 00:00:00', '2020-03-10T00:00:00.000Z', '-', '23', 33, np.nan, '', None, '2020-03-10T00:00:00.000Z', '2026-01-15 00:00:00']})
df.head(10)

                           Date
    0       2023-03-15 00:00:00
    1  2020-03-10T00:00:00.000Z
    2                         -
    3                        23
    4                        33
    5                       NaN
    6                          
    7                      None
    8  2020-03-10T00:00:00.000Z
    9       2026-01-15 00:00:00
    
df['Date_new'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], errors='coerce')
df.head(10)
    
                           Date                      Date_new
    0       2023-03-15 00:00:00 2023-03-15 00:00:00.000000000
    1  2020-03-10T00:00:00.000Z 2020-03-10 00:00:00.000000000
    2                         -                           NaT
    3                        23                           NaT
    4                        33 1970-01-01 00:00:00.000000033
    5                       NaN                           NaT
    6                                                     NaT
    7                      None                           NaT
    8  2020-03-10T00:00:00.000Z 2020-03-10 00:00:00.000000000
    9       2026-01-15 00:00:00 2026-01-15 00:00:00.000000000
    
df.Date_new.max()
    
    Timestamp('2026-01-15 00:00:00')
```

Comment: We can go this way, it's data similar to what I'm dealing with I have to get the max() of these dates equal to SQL.

Comment: see this should work and you can use max() method to get max date out of Date_new columns that I have created in the code.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should make your own date function? Apparently, according to [this](https://discuss.python.org/t/parse-z-timezone-suffix-in-datetime/2220), Python does not have any built-in parser for ISO-8601 so...

```
from datetime import datetime

def fix_iso_date_str(dstr):
    return datetime.fromisoformat(dstr.replace('Z', '+00:00'))

df['Date'] = fix_iso_date_str(df['Date'] )
```